# outlook keeps classifying my important emails as spam

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-filter

I have seen so many important emails moved to junk folder that I literally have to check mailbox every few days.

My current solution is clicking "not spam" for all the false alarm, but other than this, is there a way to fix? If not, how do I completely disable outlook's spam detection?

Comment: If only. They flag it before it even reaches you, so you're stuck with it. All you can do is keep clicking the 'not spam' & 'report' buttons until it eventually learns. [Though if someone has a better idea to fix this complete & utter garbage I'd be most happy to learn it.]

Comment: Main Outlook tab, Junk Mail settings and turn it off. That works here (my email is filtered where it is first received).

Comment: @Tetsujin - The only solution I have is have the Administrator of the Exchange server change the behavior of detected spam and/or create an exception for the domain being flagged.

Comment: @Ramhound - if only I had the ear of the admin. I don't. I'm one of many thousands, possibly millions of users. I was unfortunate that my ISP chose Office365 as their mail provider, after over a decade of providing their own service. [I set this account & domain up in 2001.] It has been a nightmare ever since. [This is a national company, owner & provider of all the copper in the UK… they copped out & rented 365 for everybody.] 'Oooh! Free MS Office!'… I haven't even installed it, don't need it.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Understood.  **I am one of hundreds of thousands**  However, my experience with Office 365 configuration, has been positive.  I went from moving 100 MB limit and having to more email storage than I know what to do with.  The transition also wasn't "free" since my employer still pays for it but they got rid of the individual servers for each segment.

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm even one removed from that. This is an ISP business service, which has been farmed out to 365. I don't have the space to go into detail, but as a small business client of theirs, they shot their customer base square in the face. Fine, I guess, if you actually **use** Microsoft & are invested in their paradigm, totally intractable if you're not. I don't have Office, I don't have Outlook on my computer. I can only access over web. I used to have full admin powers over all my employees' accounts - they took that away. I'm left with a POP view into an IMAP solution. It sucks :/

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that many emails you received have been moved to Junk folder, considering that you have set a higher protection level and blocked more messages, it is recommended that you could [change the level of junk email protection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-level-of-protection-in-the-junk-email-filter-e89c12d8-9d61-4320-8c57-d982c8d52f6b) to check if there're any difference.

In addition, if the emails moved to the Junk folder have similar characteristics, such as coming from the same sender or the same domain, it is recommended that you could try to add the sender or domain names to the Safe Senders(Click Home > Delete group > Junk > Junk E-mail Options>Safe Senders>Add), so that email addresses and domain names in the Safe Senders list are never treated as junk email, regulations of the content of the message.

[image]

[image]

Hope to help you!

***Updated:***

For web app, you can also change the settings of the Junk email. For more information, please refer to:

[Block or allow (junk email settings)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/block-or-allow-junk-email-settings-48c9f6f7-2309-4f95-9a4d-de987e880e46#bkmk_safesenders)

[Filter junk email and spam in Outlook on the web](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-junk-email-and-spam-in-outlook-on-the-web-db786e79-54e2-40cc-904f-d89d57b7f41d)

Comment: This works for Windows client, not for web app.

Comment: Hi Rahn, i have updated my reply in the above reply. Hope it will help you!

Comment: Hi Rahn, just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.